# NodeJS server throws "Updgrade Required" on loading pages even after being updated to latest npm version

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nodeclipse

I have a node project developed with NodeJS version 5.4.x and NPM version with 3.3.12 on windows. When i tried to run the project after a Quite sometime now it throws "Upgrade Required" on page loaded(HTTP Error code - 426).

Then I have installed NodeJs with 5.5 Stable. And ran couple of commands like

```
> npm install npm -g
> npm cache clean -f
> npm update -g
```

And Npm version is upgraded to 3.5.3. And i ran the node js project on eclipse but still the issue persist. Need help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue happened because of the installation conflict between non-administrative and administrative server instance. The installation was done with administrator and somehow my instance was always working on non-administrative instance. With admin rights I'm able to resolve this.