# Node js server not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am trying to make a node js server with ws module. But it's not working. It says upgrade required.

My server side code:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server; 
wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8080});

wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log('Msg received in server: %s ', message);
});

ws.send('Msg from server');
});
```

Client side code:

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/');
ws.on('open', function() {
  ws.send('Msg from client');
});
ws.on('message', function(data, flags) {
  console.log('Msg received in client: %s ', data);
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any error message?

Comment: the error message:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 426 (Upgrade Required)

Comment: It generally means that your server side `WebSocket` and client side `WebSocket` are of different version. Try to check that.

Answer (score 0):

Running `npm update` as an administrator should update the packages and solve your issue.

[Here is a similar issue reported fixed by another user.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34924698/nodejs-server-throws-updgrade-required-on-loading-pages-even-after-being-updat)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't able to fix the problem. Then I used Socket.io. It works well.